# mybatis ordering by many fields with dynamic sql

Tags: ibatis, mybatis

Is there a cleaner way of doing the next :

```
<select id="getWithQueryData" resultMap="usuarioResult" parameterType="my.QueryData" >
select * from t_user 
 <if test="fieldName != null and ascDesc != null">
    order by
        <choose>  
            <when test="fieldName == 'name'">
                c_name 
            </when>         
            <when test="fieldName == 'lastName'">
                c_last_name 
            </when> 
            <when test="fieldName == 'email'">
                c_email 
            </when> 
            <when test="fieldName == 'password'">
                c_password 
            </when> 
            <when test="fieldName == 'age'">
                i_age
            </when>                                                             
        </choose>               
        <if test="ascDesc == 'asc'">
            asc 
        </if>            
        <if test="ascDesc == 'desc'">
            desc 
        </if>   
 </if>
limit #{limit} offset #{offset};
```

As you could infer, QueryData looks like:

```
public class FiltroBusquedaVO {

private Integer offset;
private Integer limit;
private String fieldName;
private String ascDesc; ... }
```

Would be nice if I could get a column name given a fieldName. I mean, the result maps have that info. But it seems I can not get it from the xml.

My example has just 5 fields, but what about 20 fields? Is there another way around of doing this less verbose?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See my answer on a similar problem.

[Mybatis map property to column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13030708/mybatis-map-property-to-column/14556066#14556066)

But with that the only downside is you java code will know about the column names.

Comment: How about `order by`, I don't see `order by` in your example. The value type of `ascDesc` is String. However sql need ASC|DESC as keyword. Is it possible to convert Java String to sql keyword?

Comment: I think you can add order by columns along with ASC/DESC into an array list and then conditionally include it in the query if the map contains the "order_by" key.

Comment: Thanks for your attention and sorry for my ambiguous quesion. I'm curious about if there are many fields to oder by like `order by col1 col1AscDesc, col2 col2AscDesc`. Is it possible not to write `<if test="col1AscDesc == 'asc'"> asc </if>`, just `order by col1 col1AscDesc`. Since col1AscDesc is a Java String, mysql doesn't recoginize it as keywords. I tried to google `convert string to mysql keyword` but that doesn't help.

Answer (score 1):

This is how I did it:

```
List<ProjectLockDBO> getProjectsLocks(@Param("projectId") Integer projectId, @Param("userId") Integer userId, @Param("limit") Integer limit,
            @Param("offset") Integer offset, @Param("sortAsc") List<String> sortAsc, @Param("sortDesc") List<String> sortDesc);

<select id="getProjectsLocks" resultMap="ProjectLockResult">
        SELECT pl.id,
               pl.project_id,
               pl.notes,
               pl.created_by_id,
               pl.created_at,
               u.id AS user_id,
               u.email AS user_email,
               u.first_name AS user_first_name,
               u.last_name AS user_last_name
        FROM projects_locks pl
        LEFT JOIN users u ON u.id = pl.created_by_id
        WHERE 1=1
        <if test="projectId != null"> AND pl.project_id = #{projectId}</if>
        <if test="userId != null"> AND pl.created_by_id = #{userId}</if>
        <choose>
            <when test="sortAsc != null or sortDesc != null">
                ORDER BY <if test="sortAsc != null">
                    <foreach collection="sortAsc" item="element" open="" close=" ASC" separator=",">
                        ${element}
                    </foreach>
                </if>
                <if test="sortAsc != null and sortDesc != null">, </if>
                <if test="sortDesc != null">
                    <foreach collection="sortDesc" item="element" open="" close=" DESC" separator=",">
                        ${element}
                    </foreach>
                </if>
            </when>
            <otherwise>ORDER BY pl.id;</otherwise>
        </choose>
        <if test="limit != null">LIMIT #{limit}</if>
        <if test="offset != null">OFFSET #{offset}</if>
    </select>
```

Where the 2 lists will contain strings like: "pl.project_id", "pl.id",

The critical part here is the dollar sign "$" in front of the {element}. If you will use the standard #, it won't work.