# Mybatis map property to column

Tags: mybatis

I have a query mapper like the following:

```
<select id="searchSomething" parameterType="SomeType" resultType="SomeOtherType">
  select xxxxx
  from T_XXXX
  where 1=1
  <if test="propertyName == 'userName'">
    and USER_NAME = #{propertyValue}
  </if>
  <if test="propertyName == 'address'">
    and ADDRESS = #{propertyValue}
  </if>
  <if test="propertyName == 'taskDate'">
    and TASK_DATE = #{propertyValue}
  </if>
  <if test="propertyName == 'phone1'">
    and PHONE_1 = #{propertyValue}
  </if>
  <if test="propertyName == 'phone2'">
    and PHONE_2 = #{propertyValue}
  </if>
  ...
</select>
```

There are so many properties. How can i simply map the property name to column name, like the following:

```
<select id="searchSomething" parameterType="SomeType" resultType="SomeOtherType">
  select xxxxx
  from T_XXXX
  where 1=1
    and 
    <propertyToColumn property="propertyName" />
      = #{propertyValue}
</select>
```

Is there something like "propertyToColumn" in MyBatis?

I found "insertColumnName" in iBatis, is it removed from MyBatis?

The parameterType is a java class like:

```
public class SomeType{
  private String propertyName;
  private String propertyValue;
  ... getters and setters
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that it could be better if you do the "parameter-column" conversion in your code, and pass the result column as parameter. In that case you could do something like this:

```
<select id="searchSomething" parameterType="SomeType" resultType="SomeOtherType">
  select xxxxx
  from T_XXXX
  where 1=1
    and 
   ${propertyColumn} = #{propertyValue}
</select>
```

Of course, you will need to add the **propertyColumn** to your VO.

Answer (score 2):

One way of doing this is by using :

Prepare two ArrayLists, one with propertyNames and another with propertValues.
Make sure they are in proper order, ie propValuesList[i] should have the value for propNamesList[i].

Put then in a HashMap and pass it as input to mapped statement:

```
Map<String,Object> map = new HashMap<String,Object>();
List<String> propNamesList = new ArrayList<String>();
List<String> propValuesList = new ArrayList<String>();
propNamesList.add(0, "USER_NAME");
propNamesList.add(1, "ADDRESS");

propValuesList.add(0, "admin");
propValuesList.add(1, "hyderabad");

map.put("propNames",propNamesList);
map.put("propValues",propValuesList);
```

Then in mapped statement:

```
<select id="selectUsers" parameterType="hashmap" resultMap="UserResult">
    select * from users
    where 1 =1
    <if test="propNames != null and propValues != null">
       <foreach item="propName" index="index" collection="propNames">
        and #{propName} = #{propValues[${index}]}
       </foreach>
    </if>
 </select>
```

Observe the use of **${index}** instead of **#{index}**.

Comment: This means i must keep the property-column map in java code. but it seems the only way to do this. Thank you.